# Как передать правильно из mysql в php if else?

Tags: php, mysql, if

Задача состоит в том что бы прежде чем передать запрос на сервер мне нужно получить от mysql значение статуса,
status == 0 или status == 1
чуть ниже этого кода

```
if ($_POST['save']) {
    $sql = '
            update osvet
            set
                gara = %s,
                user_id = %s,
                status = 0
            where
                id = %s
            ';

            $this->db->query($sql, array(

                $gara,
                $this->getUser->id,
                $status,

                (int)$this->url[2]

            ));
```

как все это правильно составить?

```
if ($sql['status'] == 0)) { 
    $this->db->query("
            update pup
            set `yes` = `yes`+1
            where id = '".$this->getUser->id."'
        ");
} elseif ($sql['status'] == 1)) {
$this->db->query("
            update pup
            set `yes` = `yes`+2
            where id = '".$this->getUser->id."'
        ");
}
```

к сожалению я только начал все это дело не

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как можно заметить, Вам необходимо выполнить один и тот же запрос, но с разным значением параметра. Сведём задачу к нахождению необходимого значения, а запрос в тексте программы будет один.

Используя ассоциативный массив соответствия status-а yes-у

```
$yes = array(
    0 => "yes1"
    1 => "yes2"
);

...

$this->db->query(
    "update pup ".
       "set `yes` = '".($yes[$sql['status']])."' ".
     "where id = '".$this->getUser->id."'"
);
```

Множество значений status и yes можно расширять сколь угодно много.

Используя тернарный оператор

```
$this->db->query(
    "update pup ".
       "set `yes` = '".($sql['status'] == 0 ? "yes1" : "yes2")."' ".
     "where id = '".$this->getUser->id."'"
);
```

status должен принимать всего два значения.

Используя if (или swith, который приводить в пример не буду, хотя он и будет гораздо приятнее if-а и не намного хуже ассоциативного массива)

```
function yes(status) {
    if (status == 0) {
        return "yes1";
    } (status == 1) {
        return "yes2";
    } else {
        return ""; // вернуть какое-то значение по умолчанию или кинуть исключение
    }
}

...

$this->db->query(
    "update pup ".
       "set `yes` = '".(yes($sql['status']))."' ".
     "where id = '".$this->getUser->id."'"
);
```

Тоже можно понаделать сколь угодно много status-ов, продолжая elseif-ить.

Comment: не хочет работать.

Comment: Должны же быть какие-то сообщения об ошибках или другие признаки "не хочет работать". Может какая-то опечатка, синтаксическая ошибка.  Или вопрос понят неверно и ответ соответственно на другой вопрос. Нельзя просто так брать и копипастить с сайтов в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

Выберите селектом необходимое поле статус из своей таблицы соответствующее своей записи, сохраните в переменную и делайте с ней(переменной) что хотите.

Comment: чет вообще не выходит с этим селектом, можете показать пример

Comment: Что то на подобие `SELECT status FROM pup WHERE id = '$this->getUser->id' `

Comment: ну в принципе я такое и сделал, у меня не получается вывести на if else

Comment: @TarasM. у меня не получается вывести на if else
покажи если знаешь подробней